# How do I copy an installed steam game on my PC to an external hard drive?

Tags: steam, pc, hard-drive

I have installed a game using Steam and it is already on my PC.

How do I copy the game into an external hard drive?

Comment: Note that the game will always require a running, logged-on Steam client to work. If you take the hard drive to another PC which does not have Steam installed, or the logged-on Steam user doesn't have that game in their library, the game will not run.

Answer (score 46):

1. Steam → Settings → Downloads → Steam Library Folders
2. Click "Add Library Folder" (Add your external drive)
3. Save and Close
4. Go to your Library
5. Right click on the game → Properties → Local Files
6. Click "Move Install Folder..."
7. Choose your external drive, and click Move

You can play off the external, you can even move the external drive to another PC and link the library to that PC's steam and now you have it installed on whatever Steam is currently booted with the external.

[image: Adding steam library folder]

[image: Moving game to another library]

Comment: Can i play both on PC and in the hard drive as well?

Comment: On 2 different PCs sure, but not on the same time. If all you're doing is trying to avoid re downloading, just do the move once, then copy the data back to the first drive.

Comment: You can have steam folders both places.  You still need steam.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not necessarily always, though it is sometimes true. Some games can be launched directly from their .exe files and run directly (Steam won't log the play time, and you can't get achievements). Though some games do cause the Steam client to launch even when started this way.

Comment: Really? Nice to know 

Comment: @Viper_Sb If the goal is to avoid re-downloading, OP should be using "backup game files" as opposed to move folder.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen DRM-free games, like Kerbals I screenshooted, generally can work without Steam. You can just copy their "Local files" to be safe from autoupdate screwing up your modded playthrough :)